# How can an string be replaced in JavaScript with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can a string be replaced in Javascript with regex ?

A particular regular expression is bugging me right now. I simply want to replace the `count=15` in a string like:

```
countryNo=-1&count=15&page=2
```

How can I get a format like given below:

```
countryNo=-1&count=**20**&page=2
```

Or

```
countryNo=-1&count=**30**&page=2
```

I have tried the following:

```
var x = 'countryNo=-1&count=15&page=2';
x = x.replace('count=\d{2}', 'count=30');
```

Nothing happens. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regex literal, not a string literal:

```
x = x.replace(/count=\d{2}/, 'count=30');
```

Reference: [MDN on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

As an aside, you could be DRYer, you don't have to repeat `"count="`:

```
x = x.replace(/(count=)\d{2}/, '$130');
```

Comment: For completness sake, could you explain `DRYer` (edit)cheers!

Comment: @Neurofluxation It means "more DRY", with DRY being an acronym for "Don't Repeat Yourself", which is an important principle for maintainable coding.

Comment: You know... Programming since I was 10 or 11 and never heard the acronym DRY. I've heard Don't Repeat Yourself a lot, but never DRY. Here, have an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying your regular expression as a string. Use:

```
x = x.replace(/count=\d{2}/, 'count=30');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Regex from the string literal

try following

```
x = x.replace(/count=\d{2}/, 'count=30');
```